# How to center a UIImage to UIButton?

Tags: uiimage, uibutton

I want to know how to center a UIImage to UIButton. I am using the setImage method of UIButton to place the UIImage..

Answer (score 14):

You can use the contentMode Property:

```
button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Comment: Even with that, uibutton shows image at right alignment

Answer (score 5):

Remove the text from the UIButton before setting the content mode

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you might have the wrong content alignment. Make sure they are both in the center with :

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```